# Searching for strings in lists inside Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, indexing

I'm trying to search for strings within lists that are contained in a pandas dataframe, see this one example:

```
       userAuthor     hashtagsMessage
post_1    nytimes            [#Emmys]
post_2        TMZ                  []
post_3     Forbes        [#BTSatUNGA]
post_4    nytimes            [#Emmys]
post_5     Forbes  [#BTS, #BTSatUNGA]
```

As you have noticed, the column that hosts such lists is 'hashtagsMessage'. I've tried using conventional methods for string searching but I've not been able to.

If I wanted to look for an exact match for '#BTS', with a conventional method, you could use some of these options, like:

```
df['hashtagsMessage'].str.contains("#BTS", case=False)
```

or

```
df['hashtagsMessage']=="#BTS"
```

Or similar. Unfortunately, these approaches do not work for lists, I have to make an extra step I suppose to index inside the list while I'm searching in the DataFrame but I'm not really sure how to do this part.

Any help is entirely appreciated!

Comment: Do you search for the tag '#BTS' or a partial tag and match '#BTSatUNGA'?

Comment: @Corralien hi, forgot to add. Exact matches. Question was edited, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` or `apply`:

```
>>> df['hashtagsMessage'].map(lambda x: '#BTS' in x)

post_1    False
post_2    False
post_3    False
post_4    False
post_5     True
Name: hashtagsMessage, dtype: bool
```

**Update**

A more vectorizable way using `explode`:

```
>>> df.loc[df['hashtagsMessage'].explode().eq('#BTS').loc[lambda x: x].index]

       userAuthor     hashtagsMessage
post_5     Forbes  [#BTS, #BTSatUNGA]
```

Comment: I search for the tag '#BTS' and not a partial match.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple anonymous function employing a list-comprehension and `any()` e.g.:

Edit: I originally presumed you wanted any tag *containing* '#BTS', and just edited to find only exact match(es) :)

```
In [10]: df = pd.DataFrame({'hashtagsMessage':[
                            [], ["#BTSatUNGA"],
                            ["#Emmys"], ['#BTS', '#BTSatUNGA']]})

In [18]: df['hashtagsMessage'].apply(lambda lst: any(s for s in lst
                                                     if s == "#BTS"))
Out[18]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: hashtagsMessage, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I forgot to be more clear in the original question, but your approach I also liked very much because it will have other uses cases (similar actually) where matching doesn't need to be exact.

Comment: @AquilesPáez: ok! happy coding to you :)

Answer (score 1):

Please search for raw string

if not actual list use:

```
df['hashtagsMessage'].str.contains(r'#BTS')
```

if list please use

```
df['hashtagsMessage'].astype(str).str.contains(r'#BTS')
```